# print $data in echo?

Tags: php, json

My code:

```
$url = "https://apilayer.net/api/live?currencies=USD,EUR,GBP&source=USD&format=1";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$thedata = json_decode($json, true);

echo $thedata['quotes']['USDEUR'];
```

This is the JSON I get:

```
"quotes":{
  "USDUSD":1,
  "USDEUR":0.90629,
  "USDGBP":0.63802
}
```

So now I have a database and column name currency. So I want to get currency table into php. 
and currency = Like

```
id  -  currency
1   -  USD
2   -  GBP
3   -  USD
AND MORE ...
```

So I do this:

```
$url = "https://apilayer.net/api/live?currencies=USD,EUR,GBP&source=$data[currency]&format=1";
```

But in echo data I want to print

```
echo $thedata['quotes']['USDEUR'];
```

But I want to change USD TO $data[currency]

Like this:

```
echo $thedata['quotes']['$data[currency]EUR'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo $thedata['quotes']["$data[currency]EUR"];
```

Comment: but it print JUST "USD" , IWANA PRINT USDEUR .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo $thedata['quotes']['$data[currency]'].$thedata['quotes']['EUR'];
```

The . combines the two strings into one echo, so you should get your desired output.

Comment: THX U, BUT IT DONT WORK ?

Comment: What is $data['currency']? Could you amend your main post with that info?

Comment: echo $thedata['quotes'][$data['currency]'] . 'USD'];
   ITS WORK WITH THIS